# How to get property of object?

Tags: angular

i m getting json from server

```
 getTextContent() {
   this._main.getVar()
   .subscribe(
     text_content => this.text_content = text_content,
     error => console.error('Error: ' + this.errorMessage),
     () => console.log('Completed!',this.text_content));
}
```

in console and on the screen i see

[image]

That's good. But when i try to show `{{text_content.category_content.home}}` on the screen i get an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'category_content' of undefined in [{{text_content.category_content.home}} in HomeComponent@1:3]`
Should i use dot to get object's property or anything else?

**Update**

```
import {Component,OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/common';
import {MainService} from '../../shared/services/main.service';
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import {Title} from 'angular2/platform/browser';

 @Component({
   selector: 'sd-home',
   moduleId: module.id,
   viewProviders: [MainService],
   templateUrl: './home.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
   directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES]
 })
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  public http:Http;
  public pageTitle : String;
  private text_content : Object;
  private errorMessage : String;
 constructor (private _title:Title, private _main:MainService) {
  }
 ngOnInit() {
    this.getTextContent();
    console.log('text',this.text_content.category_content);
   }

 getTextContent() {
   this._main.getVar()
   .subscribe(
     text_content => this.text_content = text_content,
     error => console.error('Error: ' + this.errorMessage),
     () => console.log('Completed!',this.text_content));
    }
    }
```

Property 'category_content' does not exist on type 'Object'

Comment: What do you get with `console.log(text_content.category_content)`?

Comment: He would get the same error. Are you sure you are in the correct context? Notice how you use `this` from within `getTextContent`. Find out where `text_content` really is.

Comment: Yes. The same error. i updated my question

Comment: `Cannot read property 'category_content' of undefined` means that it is your object `text_content` that is undefined. You've got a scoping issue.

Comment: Have you tried `{{text_content.?category_content.home}}` ?  `text_content` is retrieved asynchronously. For the same reason you shouldn't log `this.text_content....`, use `JSON.stringify(this.text_content)` to log current object state.

Comment: Read the docs https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#elvis

Comment: Yes!!! It works with `<div>{{text_content?.category_content?.home}}</div>`

Comment: but it doesn't work in script. e.g. `this._title.setTitle(this.text_content.category_content.title);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `text_content` in your `$scope`. So at the end of your success case you need `$scope.text_content = this.text_content`. This will make it available to the digester and it will be rendered properly.

Comment: What do you mean by `$scope` in `Angular2`?

Comment: Ah, I missed the "angular2" tag. Never mind, carry on.

Comment: You should probably delete your answer, I doubt it could help anyone ; even if we were talking about angularjs, OP is trying to access the object in a function, which would be defined in the controller, thus making access through `$scope` not necessary.

Comment: From the question, "i try to show {{text_content.category_content.home}} on the screen". Displaying the value on the rendered page is the root of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Could be `angular2 zone` issue,

```
import {NgZone} from 'angular2/core';
 constructor (private _title:Title, private _main:MainService,private zone:NgZone) {
  }
getTextContent() {
    this.zone.run(()=>
    this._main.getVar()
              .subscribe(
                text_content => this.text_content = text_content,
                error => console.error('Error: ' + this.errorMessage),
                () => console.log('Completed!',this.text_content));

              );
}
```

try out this.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
{{text_content?.category_content?.home}}
```

`text_content` is not yet available when Angular tries to resolve the binding the first time because the data are processed async.

Comment: yes, it works in template, but it doesn't work in scripts. I can't do something like this `this._title.setTitle(this.text_content.category_content.title);` in my class. Even with elvis

Comment: Sorry, I missed that this was already mentioned in the comments. The code you provided in the comment isn't included in your question. `this._title.setTitle(this.text_content?.category_content.title);` should work or you could wrap it in `if(this.text_content) { ... }`

Comment: ngOnInit() {
  this.getTextContent();
    console.log('content',this.text_content);
  `if(this.text_content) {
    console.log('content',this.text_content);
  this.pageTitle = this.text_content?.category_content?.title;
    this._title.setTitle(this.pageTitle);
  }`   - error because `this.text_content` undefined. But works in template (